# Laravel 7 queued email very slow with attachment but fast without

Tags: laravel, email, queue, attachment, dispatch

I use Laravel 7 queues / jobs to send a newsletter to multiple addresses and it works well and rather fast. But when I send a single email with attachment (22ko PDF), it takes nearly 3 - 5 minutes to get through. Any clues? I use database driver and Mailgun API.

How can I see if the slow process time is from Laravel app or Mailgun or else?

I tried to use `SendEmailJob::dispatchNow($data);` but it does not speed up the process.

app\Http\controllers/EmailController.php

```
App\EmailController

use App\Job\SendEmailJob;
public function send()
{

$data = array(
'from_name'=>from_name',
'from_email'=>'admin@domain.com',
'to_name'=>$user->firstname." ".$user->name,
'to_email'=>$user->email,
'subject'=>'This is test email',
'reply_to'=>noreply@domain.com,
'model'=>$invoice,
'locale'=>app()->getLocale(),
'user'=>$user,
'view'=>'emails.invoice',
'filefullpath'=>$fullfilepath,
);

SendEmailJob::dispatch($data);

}
```

App\Jobs\SendEmailJob.php

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\Mail\SendView;
use Mail;

class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {


        $email = new SendView($this->data);
        $email->replyTo($this->data['reply_to']);
        $email->subject($this->data['subject']);

        if(isset($this->data['filefullpath']))
        {
            $email->attach($this->data['filefullpath']);
        }
        Mail::to($this->data['to_email'], $this->data['to_name'])->send($email);

    }
}
```

App\Mail\SendView.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendView extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {


        $view = $this->data['view'];
        $user = $this->data['user'];
        $model = $this->data['model'];
        $locale = $this->data['locale'];
        $array = $this->data['array'];

        return $this->view($view, compact('user', 'model','locale','array'));
    }
}
```

Please help! Thanks.